# gradually interleave one list with another

Tags: python, python-3.x, iteration, combinations

i tried to gradually interleave one list with another. i mean: starting from the lists

```
a0 = list(range(3))      # [0, 1, 2]
a1 = list(range(10, 13)) # [10, 11, 12]
```

i would like to be able to iterate over the combinations

```
[0, 1, 2]
[10, 1, 2]
[0, 11, 2]
[10, 11, 2]
[0, 1, 12]
[10, 1, 12]
[0, 11, 12]
[10, 11, 12]
```

where first no element of `a0` is replaced by the corresponding element of `a1`, then one, then two and then all of them.

what i came up with so far i this:

```
a01 = list(zip(a0, a1))

for i in range(1<<len(a0)):
    print(list(item[(i >> j) & 1] for j, item in enumerate(a01)))
```

where i `zip` the lists together and use `i` as a flag that tells me from what list to select an element.

this seems quite inelegant. is there something more elegant? i feel that [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) provides something that could be used here but i could not figure out anything so far.

---

the suggestion in the [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533905/get-the-cartesian-product-of-a-series-of-lists) applied here is:

```
from itertools import product

for item in product(*zip(a0, a1)):
    print(item)
```

this produces the desired results (in a different order).

to get the order correct [meowgoesthedog](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8204776/meowgoesthedog) suggests in the comments:

```
list(map(lambda x: tuple(reversed(x)), product(*reversed(list(zip(a0, a1))))))
```

this answers the question.

Comment: take a look at `itertools.roundrobin()` it could maybe interest you. [Here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes)'s a link to the recipe.

Comment: You're right - `itertools` does provide what you want: it's called `itertools.product` and I'll refer you to a previous question :)

Comment: Judging by the silence on this question, you more or less have the best/shortest way of doing this. Minor tweaks maybe.

Comment: To add to your edit, a variant which produces the correct order: `list(map(lambda x: tuple(reversed(x)), product(*reversed(list(zip(a0, a1))))))` – not exactly pretty (or as impressive as your solution with bit math) :S

Comment: @meowgoesthedog thanks! that is quite some python-fu! will update that in the 'answer' section of the question. if you want i can vote to reopen the question and you can post that as an answer (would delete it in the question then...)